# GTM formatting for "Convert null to..."

Tags: google-tag-manager, schema.org, json-ld

I use GTM for my schema.org data in JSON-LD.
I have a dom element variable named "Product-category", but when the element isn't present it is returning "null" as a string and seems to be ignoring the formatting for "Convert null to...".

I tried

```
function(){
var category = {{Product-category}};
return category.replace("", "smartphone");
}
```

But the result is "smartphonenull"

How can I convert "null" by a simple text as "smartphone" ?